# adding const to member function argument produces compile error

Tags: c++, function-qualifier

I have the following code:

```
void readTable(const Table& table)
{
  for (auto& r: table)
    {
      auto state = r["UX"] == std::string("Yes");
      std::cout << state << '\n';
    }

}
```

table is defined as

```
using Row = std::map<std::string, std::string>;
using Table = std::vector<Row>;
```

My table read function does not change the Table, so I added the const to the readTable(const Table& table). Compiler does not like this change.
Is this not the right way of telling the compiler that the table is not supposed to change ?

Comment: `r["UX"]` requires `r` to be non-const because it may need to add an entry to the map if not already present.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik what is the work aroud ?  I know that map has that element.

Comment: @RingZero [std::map::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find)?